# ERROR: Could not build wheels for atari-py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, windows, openai-gym

i'm trying to install OpenAI Gym on windows since a few days and i was mainly following the instructions given in https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-openai-gym-in-a-windows-environment-338969e24d30. I installed Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools and the commands until conda install git worked fine. But the command pip install git+https://github.com/Kojoley/atari-py.git always throws an error, no matter what I change. The error is (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcxP2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lEwG.png). I have looked for fixes, but no matter what I did, the error was the same

I installed atari-py manually from https://github.com/openai/atari-py, it worked but the wheels could not be installed
I installed cmake, but the problem remained
I installed visual studio toolbox correctly